# Removing Shaperenderer shapes from screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I drew different shapes using Shaperenderer (LibGDX) and hooked them to Box2d world bodies and make them fall under the effect of gravity. My question is how to remove them from the screen once they hit the bottom ??? Thank you.

Thanks Kevin for your reply. probably I was not too clear on my question. I will put a snippet of my code to help clarify my question:

```
BodyDef floorDef = new BodyDef(); 
floorDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;  
floorDef.position.set(0f,0f);

PolygonShape floorShape = new PolygonShape();
floorShape.setAsBox(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),10f); 
floor = world.createBody(floorDef); 
floor.createFixture(floorShape, 1f); 

BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
bodyDef.position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
shape.setPosition(new Vector2(0f,0f));
shape.setRadius(80f);
FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
fixtureDef.shape = shape;
fixtureDef.density = 0.5f;
body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

world.setContactListener(new ContactListener() {

            @Override
            public void beginContact(Contact contact) {

                if((contact.getFixtureA().getBody() == body &&
                        contact.getFixtureB().getBody() == floor)
                        ||
                        (contact.getFixtureA().getBody() == floor &&
                                contact.getFixtureB().getBody() == body)) {
                    Colliding = true;
                    collisionSound.play(1.0f);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void endContact(Contact contact) {


                if((contact.getFixtureA().getBody() == body || contact.getFixtureB().getBody() == body)) {

                    world.destroyBody(body);

                    Colliding = false;

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void postSolve(Contact arg0, ContactImpulse arg1) {

            }

            @Override
            public void preSolve(Contact arg0, Manifold arg1) {

            }
        });

        // Shape is the only disposable of the lot, so get rid of it
        shape.dispose();

        floorShape.dispose();
    }


  @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        world.step(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 6, 2);

        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

        stage.draw();

        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
        Gdx.gl20.glLineWidth(10);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.CHARTREUSE);
        shapeRenderer.rect(floor.getPosition().x,floor.getPosition().y,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),10f);
        shapeRenderer.end();
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
        Gdx.gl20.glLineWidth(10);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.FOREST);
        shapeRenderer.circle(body.getPosition().x ,body.getPosition().y ,80f);
        shapeRenderer.end();

    }
```

So I want to delete the shape created by shaperenderer highlighted between the asterisks.

Comment: remove that body when reaches at the bottom.

Comment: Are you really using JBox2D ? if so i recommand you to use libGDX box2D binding which has better integration and better performences.

Comment: Thanks Abishek for your reply. Indeed I removed the body from the world, but the fact I am attributing the position of the shape to the body position as it falls, so removing the body from the world has no bearing on the existence of the shape.

Comment: Thanks mgsx-dev. Sorry I am using LibGDX Box2d.

Comment: You can detect the collision with the ground by using something called "ContactListener" which is provided in libgdx.Once you detect the collision, remove the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing ShapeRenderer Shapes from Screen -> We are not adding something so there is no concept of removing. Like we **add** Box2d body into physics World so we can **remove** body from that world.

We're drawing Shapes on screen so somehow, I've to stop that drawing part.
My ShapeRenderer shape is view and it's model is Box2d body so remove that body when body reaches at bottom.

```
private Array<Body> array;

@Override
public void create(){         //create or show depending on who is parent
    array=new ArrayList<Body>();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    ....
    world.getBodies(array);
    for (Body body:array){
        if(body.getType()== BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody) { // I've to draw only circle
            shapeRenderer.circle(body.getPosition().x ,body.getPosition().y ,80f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Abhishek

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong Abhishek . What I understood from your snippet is to put the continuous existing of the circle to the existing of the body that is glued to it. So once the body is removed from the world, no more rendering of the shape happened. is that right??

Comment: Go it! Thanks mate